# Php - upload webservice php to server

Tags: php

I am android developer , I have no experience with php but I have requirement to upload web site to linux server , I am using WinSCP to upload web site .

here is screenshot for server side , in which folder should I upload it , and how to access it to using it as web service in my mobile

**UPDATE**

the site Amazon aws hosting

[image]

Comment: please create your own folder link 'test' and upload your webservice in test folder

Comment: in any place or must have certain place

Comment: and how can I access it , I put all files in home directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends where the web server is configured to serve files from. Common locations are a `public_html` or `www` or `htdocs` directory in your home folder (if you are using a shared server), or in `/var/www` or `/srv/www` for dedicated servers.

Again, accessing it depends on how the web server is configured. It might just use an IP address, or it may have a domain name pointing at it. Whomever set up the server will have this information.

Comment: how can I get info for my web server ?

Comment: @MinaFawzy: Whoever maintains the web server should be able to provide that.

Comment: I try create any folder but it give me Permission denied.
Error code: 3